# i'm having trouble with my django code while i deleting the data from the table form on click of the delete button

Tags: python, django

But it will showing an error which is (TypeError at /deletecase deletecase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk') please help me out this

Here is the url link of the page:

````
```path("deletecase",views.deletecase,name="deletecase")```
````

THE VIEW FILE FUNCTION:

````
```
def policcasesdetails(request):
    cases=Case.objects.all()
    return render(request,'policeside/policcasesdetails.html',{'cases':cases})

def deletecase(request,pk):
    obj=Case.objects.get(id=pk)
    obj.delete()
    return HttpResponse("Data is Deleted")
```
````

AND THE FORM IS:-

```
    <div class="container">
       <div class="content-middle">
          <div class="col-md-12 sed-in">
             <h3>Cases Details</h3>
             {% for i in cases %}
             <div class="col-md-4 sed-top">
                <div class="top-sed">
                   <!-- <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" class="img-responsive" alt=""> -->
                   <!-- <label><span>{{ i.oname }}</span></label> -->
                </div>
                <h4>
                   Case Number- <a>{{i.casenumber}}</a>
                </h4>
                <p>Case Name-  <a href="#">{{i.casename}}</a></p>
                <p>Case Result- <a href="">{{ i.caseresult }}</a></p>
                <p>Case Conclusion- <a href="">{{ i.casecoclusion }}</a></p>
                <p><a href="{% url 'deletecase' i.id %}">
                   <button type="submit" value="delete" class="btn btn- 
                      danger">Delete</button>
                </p>
             </div>
             {% endfor %}
             <div class="clearfix"> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to fix your URL so that it has a `pk` variable in it. Also you shouldn't be deleting things via GET requests, especially since you're not doing any checking that the user has permission to delete that particular thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your URL, pk is missing.

```
path("deletecase/<id>/",views.deletecase,name="deletecase")
```

This should solve your issue